# Duplicate Sagittarius A* tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have tags for both [sgr-a](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sgr-a) and [sagittarius-a](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sagittarius-a), which should presumably be merged. The actual usage of both of these tags shows they are both actually being applied to questions about [Sagittarius A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*) rather than [Sagittarius A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A) (Sgr A* is a component of Sgr A). Unfortunately it isn't possible to use an asterisk in a tag name, and "sagittarius-a-star" seems misleading. Any suggestions about how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll merge them. As for your last question, we could make a [sagittarius-a-asterisk](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sagittarius-a-asterisk) tag, but since Sagittarius A* is a component of [Sagittarius A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A), I don't see the need for a separate tag.